# Can't manage to download PDF retrieved from BLOB via Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, blob

I looked around and tried a few solutions I saw, but nothing seemed to work.

So here is my case :

I have a PDF file stored in my oracle database as BLOB.
In my backend, I call my service in order to download that pdf (In my entity, the pdf is a `byte[]`) like this :

```
@GET
@Path("/downloadpdf")
@Produces("application/pdf")
public HttpServletResponse downloadPdf(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        UserGuideJpaService userGuideService = new UserGuideJpaServiceImpl();
        HashMap<String, Object> result = userGuideService.getPdfGuide();
        if ("0".equals(result.get("returnCode"))) {
            UserGuide userGuide = (userGuide) result.get("userGuide");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Cache-control", "private");
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"APP - User Guide.pdf\"");

            byte[] pdf = userGuide.getPdf();

            if (pdf != null) {
                response.setContentLength(pdf.length);
                ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                out.write(pdf);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Back to my front-end, I have this :

**NOTE :** This is what my `response.data` looks like (it's a string) :

> %PDF-1.4 %����
>
> 8 0 obj << /Type /Page /Resources <<   /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text ]   /Font
>   4 0 R   /Shading 6 0 R   /ExtGState 7 0 R
>
> > > /MediaBox [0 0 595.28 864.00] /Contents 9 0 R /Parent 10 0 R >> endobj
>
> 9 0 obj << /Length 1679 /Filter [ /FlateDecode ] >> stream
>   x��X�n7��?]�84��aw�=I���Jr�v�%ڝ@�Q�a�s�+� ��r��%E_- �%���{x�|�
>   ��1������o�Oo������{����ߌj��bCN_3�81���{��̭]�9����rXU��e��T]WV����m�q5|\5�a�Ꞽ"����T0n~"�O�X��9�*#~+�b�5��7���9��������)�R/f�5xF���5�WW���eA���lr}A.'�7Ej�iƳ�*��]���\�^�+f�ܦ�UT�<��1��,�ZrE3�s��4���bzU,f�4�̎
>   �U�*7�̋��vN΋���4��'�䌜��^�Nf#!��~2��\G+�_�,��b<�2��/����WIU��V�2%��B����{Z��d�H�̀R�.�g%@�����0Ln)�9...

And javascript side :

```
$scope.downloadPdf = function() {
  APIClientService.downloadPdf().then(function(response) {
    // #1
    var URL, blob, downloadLink, downloadUrl;
    downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.target = '_blank';
    downloadLink.download = 'APP - User Guide.pdf';
    blob = new Blob([response.data], {
      type: 'application/pdf'
    });
    URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadLink.href = downloadUrl;
    document.body.append(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
    // # 2
    window.open("data:application/pdf," + encodeURI(response.data));
    // # 3
    window.open("data:application/pdf," + escape(response.data));
  });
};
```

However, this doesn't download the file or even open it.

And I'm pretty sure the pdf is correct in the backend because I managed to get it when using :

```
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Test.pdf");
    out.write(pdf);
    out.close();
```

How can I then download the pdf form my browser ? Or at least open it ?

Edit : This is the method from APIClientService :

```
({
  downloadPdf: function() {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: this.baseUrl + "/downloadpdf"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What is `APIClientService.downloadPdf`?

Comment: @Musa I've edited the question to add the method from APIClientService. The syntax might seem weird because I converted it from coffeescript, but it does call my backend method. It's basically a simple http get

Comment: You have to make sure that your call returns a binary response(instead of text), this is usually done by setting a responseType to `'blob'` or `'arraybuffer'`

Comment: In my case this would be my `@Produces("application/pdf")` annotation and my `response.setcontentType("application/pdf")` ? I don't think this supports the blob keyword, maybe with `application/octet-stream` ?

Comment: On the client side I mean

Comment: Thanks again @Musa, this was indeed my issue.
Feel free to create an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ajax requests treat you response as text, this will cause issues with non text files.

To prevent this add a binary responseType to your request, something like

```
({
  downloadPdf: function() {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: this.baseUrl + "/downloadpdf",
      responseType: "blob"
    });
  }
});
```